# text replace problem when target contains '&' symbol

Tags: command-line, replace, command

I tried to replace `if(cond1)` with `if(cond1&&cond2)` in vim, so I typed the command

```
:%s/\Vif(cond1)/if(cond1&&cond2)/g
```

but the result is
`if(cond1if(cond1)if(cond1)cond2)` and not
`if(cond1&&cond2)`

What command should I actually use?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` in a replacement is a bit special:

```
magic  nomagic  action
  &      \&     replaced with the whole matched pattern      *s/\&*
```

But you can escape it with `\`:

```
%substitute/\Vif(cond1)/if(cond1\&\&cond2)/g
```

Comment: it works, thanks a lot!